помогите понять суть задания по python
есть задание, помогите понять что надо делать , как должен выглядеть код?
Написать функцию, которая принимает список пользователей (имеющуюся структуру данных [ {}, {}, .. ]) и добавляет пользователю данные статуса. Значение статуса устанавливать
в suspicious, если пользователь младше 18 и работает или старше 18 и не работает..
в not_suspicious, если пользователь младше 18 и не работает или старше 18 и работает.
Функция должна возвращать обновленный список с пользователями.

что вообще означает вопрос "как должен выглядеть код"? Код должен выглядет как последовательность синтаксически правильных конструкций языка програмирования.

начинай есть слона по кусочкам. Сначала создай функцию, которая принимает список. Потому переходи к следующей части.

Покажите реальную  структуру данных и свой код.

Задание заключается в написании функции, которая принимает список пользователей в виде списка словарей и добавляет им ключ status со значениями suspicious или not_suspicious в зависимости от их возраста и статуса занятости.
Вам нужно:

Создать функцию, принимающую список пользователей в виде списка словарей.
Перебрать список пользователей и для каждого добавить ключ "status" со значением "suspicious" или "not_suspicious" в зависимости от их возраста и статуса занятости.
Вернуть обновленный список пользователей из функции.

Код должен содержать:

Объявление функции, которая на вход принимает лист словарей
Цикл в котором будет осуществляться перебор словарей из листа
Ветвление в результате которого, мы будет указывать значения ключа status
Возврат списка словарей из функции


Перед тем как переходить к задачам начните с основ.

это преподователю скажите, который задает задания по тому что не рассказывал на уроке

@vitaliy я вас прекрасно понимаю, на том ресурсе который в ссылке, материал, который с лихвой покроет Ваши задачки. Не сдавайтесь и удачи в изучении!
